# How can I setup an AWS lambda to access resources in two, separate VPCs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, terraform

I'm using Terraform to build an API + corresponding lambda functions.

I have some other infrastructure, which I'd like to think is nicely set up (maybe I'm wrong?):

- 2 VPCs (let's just call'em `test` and `prod`)
- Private & public subnets in each VPC
- RDS DBs launched in the private subnets

All resources are identical on both VPCs; e.g. there's a `test-private-subnet` and a `prod-private-subnet` with exactly the same specs, same for DBs, etc.

Now, I'm working on the API and the lambdas that will power said API.

I don't feel like I need a `test` & `prod` API gateway and `test` & `prod` lambdas:

- lambda code will be the same, just acting on different DB
- you can use API `stage_variables`, with different ips, to achieve a `test` vs `prod` environment for the API

But when I try and setup a lambda with the `vpc_config` block (cause I need it to be associated with the *security group* that's allowed ingress on the DBs), I get the following error:

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.lambdas.aws_lambda_function.api-lambda-users: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_lambda_function.api-lambda-users: Error creating Lambda function: InvalidParameterValueException: Security Groups are required to be in the same VPC.
status code: 400, request id: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

My lambda config looks like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "api-lambda-users" {
  provider = "PROVIDER"
  function_name    = "users"
  s3_key           = "users/${var.lambda-package-name}"
  s3_bucket        = "${var.api-lambdas-bucket}"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.lambda-role.arn}"
  handler          = "${var.handler-name}"
  runtime          = "${var.lambda-runtime}"

  vpc_config {
    security_group_ids = [
      //"${data.aws_security_group.prod-lambda.id}",
      "${data.aws_security_group.test-lambda.id}"
    ]
    subnet_ids = [
      //"${data.aws_subnet.prod-primary.id}",
      "${data.aws_subnet.test-primary.id}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice I'd ideally like to just specify them, together, in their corresponding lists.

Am I missing something?

Suggestions?

Any help, related or not, is much appreciated.

Comment: In general, it's good to have a fully-duplicated environment for Test. That way, you can experiment with changes (eg improved Lambda code) without impacting a Production environment. Given that Lambda and API Gateway cost nothing when they are not being used (except for API Gateway caching, if activated), there's no real reason to avoid creating a full test environment.

Comment: Thanks. Considered that too, but thought it was overkill. Glad to hear it isn't; probably what I'm gonna end up doing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda running inside a vpc is subject to the same networking "rules" as ec2 instances. So it can't "exist" in two VPC's. If the lambda function needs to talk vpc resources in two separate VPC's you could use something like VPC peering or just run two copies of the function in the two different vpc's.

> When you add VPC configuration to a Lambda function, it can only access resources in that VPC. If a Lambda function needs to access both VPC resources and the public Internet, the VPC needs to have a [Network Address Translation (NAT)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html) instance inside the VPC and a [VPC Peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/Welcome.html) connection.

Comment: Thanks. Probably gonna go with a lambda function / VPC, as [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein)'s comment!

Comment: The reason to build two VPCs (test and prod) is to isolate the environment, vpc peering is not a good suggestion for this case.

Comment: I agree , that's the thing amazon they give you just enough rope